How to convert the btrfs boot disk into RAID1
While I have been using linux for decades, I am still inexperienced with GRUB, efi and the rest of the boot sequence of linux.
Current I have a NUC with Intel Core i5-1340P. There is a single NVMe SSD mounted on the only NVMe slot and it is running ubuntu 24.04.1 on a btrfs partition.
I would like to add a second NVMe via a USB adaptor plugging into one of the thunderbolt ports and converting the second NVMe storage medium bootable and mirror the btrfs into a RAID1 configuration.
How do I do it? Could someone list a step by step procedures for me to follow? Any help will be deeply appreciated. 
Here is the current config.
lsblk:
$ sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT
NAME                      FSTYPE       SIZE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1                                1.8T 
├─nvme0n1p1               vfat           1G /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2               ext4           2G /boot
└─nvme0n1p3               LVM2_member  1.8T 
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv btrfs        1.8T /mnt/btr_pool

/etc/fstab
$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-LVM-fWXdedW7hsrmHC4xQSaVFs2yEhSCLw6age9unhvPhV1SxG71dRcLRr8BnktuJUaV / btrfs defaults 0 1
# Note:
#  We have changed the default subvolume id 16264 (rootfs) from original 5 (.)
#  Hence we remount the toplevel subvolume . on /mnt/btr_pool
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv /mnt/btr_pool btrfs subvolid=5,noatime 0 0

# /boot was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/86924b33-495e-41c3-bf70-14cb58fa709e /boot ext4 defaults 0 1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/05C4-5A31 /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1

# swapfile
# A separated subvolume for hosting the swapfile
# The kernel is tuned with vm.swappiness and vm.vfs_cache_pressure values located in /etc/sysctl.d/99-swappiness.conf
#  in order to lower wear and tear on the SSD.
#  Please reference https://docs.gluster.org/en/main/Administrator-Guide/Linux-Kernel-Tuning/#linux-kernel-tuning-for-glusterfs
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv /swap btrfs subvol=@swap 0 0
/swap/swapfile none swap sw 0 0

# There is a bug in samba when sharing a subvolume of btrfs and zfs that it spam errors if  the subvolume is not listed in /etc/fstab
# In order to silent it, we add an entry here for all the subvolumes shared by smbd directly
# Reference: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1735953/comments/9
# As we have switched to subvolume rootfs, we have to mount back those subvolume anyway
# for subvolume id 256 (docker)
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv /docker btrfs defaults,noatime,autodefrag,compress=zstd,commit=120,subvolid=256 0 0

$ sudo btrfs fi show /
Label: none  uuid: 68b67043-1371-434f-9efa-f4617ca1085b
    Total devices 1 FS bytes used 120.99GiB
    devid    1 size 1.82TiB used 542.08GiB path /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv

blkid
$ blkid
/dev/nvme0n1p3: UUID="J2V7eH-3HXS-VPrk-ihbo-kkhv-cCL7-Vzt6Mz" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="a72aca04-369b-463e-838e-6631f969f42a"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="05C4-5A31" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="7b316121-4693-4772-98c4-359cca6399ad"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="86924b33-495e-41c3-bf70-14cb58fa709e" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="85137027-9166-4b49-93da-75a9d647a771"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: UUID="68b67043-1371-434f-9efa-f4617ca1085b" UUID_SUB="6a5fe355-6409-4547-b13a-91157d5221b9" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="btrfs"

/boot/grub/grub.cfg
$ cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg 
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${initrdfail}" = 2 ]; then
   set initrdfail=
elif [ "${initrdfail}" = 1 ]; then
   set next_entry="${prev_entry}"
   set prev_entry=
   save_env prev_entry
   if [ "${next_entry}" ]; then
      set initrdfail=2
   fi
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function initrdfail {
    if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -n "${partuuid}" ]; then
      if [ -z "${initrdfail}" ]; then
        set initrdfail=1
        if [ -n "${boot_once}" ]; then
          set prev_entry="${default}"
          save_env prev_entry
        fi
      fi
      save_env initrdfail
    fi; fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod lvm
insmod btrfs
set root='lvmid/fWXded-W7hs-rmHC-4xQS-aVFs-2yEh-SCLw6a/ge9unh-vPhV-1SxG-71dR-cLRr-8Bnk-tuJUaV'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='lvmid/fWXded-W7hs-rmHC-4xQS-aVFs-2yEh-SCLw6a/ge9unh-vPhV-1SxG-71dR-cLRr-8Bnk-tuJUaV'  68b67043-1371-434f-9efa-f4617ca1085b
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 68b67043-1371-434f-9efa-f4617ca1085b
fi
    font="/rootfs/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_GB
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=hidden
    set timeout=0
  # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  elif sleep --interruptible 0 ; then
    set timeout=0
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if [ ${grub_platform} != pc ]; then
      set linux_gfx_mode=keep
    elif hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-68b67043-1371-434f-9efa-f4617ca1085b' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 86924b33-495e-41c3-bf70-14cb58fa709e
    linux   /vmlinuz-6.8.0-51-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ro rootflags=subvol=rootfs  
    initrd  /initrd.img-6.8.0-51-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-68b67043-1371-434f-9efa-f4617ca1085b' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 6.8.0-51-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.8.0-51-generic-advanced-68b67043-1371-434f-9efa-f4617ca1085b' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 86924b33-495e-41c3-bf70-14cb58fa709e
        echo    'Loading Linux 6.8.0-51-generic ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-6.8.0-51-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ro rootflags=subvol=rootfs  
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initrd.img-6.8.0-51-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 6.8.0-51-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.8.0-51-generic-recovery-68b67043-1371-434f-9efa-f4617ca1085b' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 86924b33-495e-41c3-bf70-14cb58fa709e
        echo    'Loading Linux 6.8.0-51-generic ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-6.8.0-51-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ro recovery nomodeset dis_ucode_ldr rootflags=subvol=rootfs 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initrd.img-6.8.0-51-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 6.8.0-50-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.8.0-50-generic-advanced-68b67043-1371-434f-9efa-f4617ca1085b' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 86924b33-495e-41c3-bf70-14cb58fa709e
        echo    'Loading Linux 6.8.0-50-generic ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-6.8.0-50-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ro rootflags=subvol=rootfs  
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initrd.img-6.8.0-50-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 6.8.0-50-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.8.0-50-generic-recovery-68b67043-1371-434f-9efa-f4617ca1085b' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 86924b33-495e-41c3-bf70-14cb58fa709e
        echo    'Loading Linux 6.8.0-50-generic ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-6.8.0-50-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ro recovery nomodeset dis_ucode_ldr rootflags=subvol=rootfs 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initrd.img-6.8.0-50-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux_zfs ###
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux_zfs ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/25_bli ###
if [ "$grub_platform" = "efi" ]; then
  insmod bli
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/25_bli ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
if [ "$grub_platform" = "efi" ]; then
    fwsetup --is-supported
    if [ "$?" = 0 ]; then
        menuentry 'UEFI Firmware Settings' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
            fwsetup
        }
    fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###

Please note that the btrfs root is mounted from a subvolume rootfs instead of the default 'subvolid=5'. It is recommended by digint
Axel Burri of btrbk for better snapshot management.
*Edited for better lsblk command and corrected the hyperlink
